# Bash: double equals vs -eq

Tags: bash, shell, arithmetic

I am doing integer comparison in bash (trying to see if the user is running as root), and I found two different ways of doing it:

Double equals:

```
if [ $UID == 0 ]
then
fi
```

-eq

```
if [ $UID -eq 0 ]
then
fi
```

I understand that there's no >= or <= in bash, only -ge and -le, so why is there a `==` if there's a `-eq`?

Is there a difference in the way it compares both sides?

Comment: Note that spaces inside brackets are required: `[ $UID -eq 0 ]`, not `[ $UID -eq 0]`.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

`==` is a `bash`-specific alias for `=`, which performs a string (lexical) comparison instead of the `-eq` numeric comparison.  (It's backwards from Perl:  the word-style operators are numeric, the symbolic ones lexical.)

Comment: Does that mean that if both sides are integers, it converts both sides to strings and then compares them?

Comment: More precisely it's the other way around:  everything is a string, `-eq` tells `bash` to interpret the strings as integers (producing `0` without a warning if a string isn't numeric).

Comment: @tjameson To give an example: `[ 01 -eq 1 ]` but `[ 01 != 1 ]`.

Comment: Note that while `==` as a `[` operator is non-standard and should not be used, it is not _bash-specific_. It was introduced by ksh and is also supported by zsh (though the first `=` needs to be quoted), yash and the GNU `[` utility (and any such utilities implemented as ksh scripts on some systems) at least).

Comment: @geekosaur I get a warning from bash v4.3.42 if my string isn't numeric: `$ if [ "hello" -eq 0 ]; then echo true; fi`
_bash: [: hello: integer expression expected_

Answer (score 14):

To elaborate on [bollovan's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/16115/62291)...

There is no `>=` or `<=` comparison operator for strings. But you could use them with the `((...))` arithmetic command to compare integers.

You can also use the other string comparison operators (`==`, `!=`, `<`, `>`, but not `=`) to compare integers if you use them inside `((...))`.

**Examples**

- Both `[[ 01 -eq 1 ]]` and `(( 01 == 1 ))` do integer comparisons. Both are true.
- Both `[[ 01 == 1 ]]` and `[ 01 = 1 ]` do string comparisons. Both are false.
- Both `(( 01 -eq 1 ))` and `(( 01 = 1 ))` will return an error.

Note: The double bracket syntax `[[...]]` and the double parentheses syntax `((...))` are not supported by all shells.

Comment: Note that (except for `mksh`/`zsh` (except in POSIX mode (though that's not a POSIX feature))), `(( 010 == 10 ))` would return false because `010` would be treated as an octal number (8 in decimal).

Comment: Note that while most `test`/`[` implementations don't have `>=`/`<=` operators (`yash`'s `[` has though), `expr` has such operators, though it will do arithmetic comparison if the arguments are recognised as numbers (`expr 01 '>=' 1` returns true, `expr X01 '>=' X1` returns false).

Answer (score 7):

If you want to do integer comparison you will better use (( )), where you can also use >= etc.

Example:

```
if (( $UID == 0 )); then
   echo "You are root"
else
   echo "You are not root"
fi
```

Comment: Or `(( UID == 0 ))` or `(( ! UID ))` for that matters. Note that `((...))` is non-standard (a `ksh` feature also supported by `bash` and `zsh` with variations).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Since UID is not boolean would  `! UID` not be more like `UID != 0`.

Comment: @Jeter-work, it's like in C / awk / perl..., `! UID` evaluates to 1 if UID is 0 or to 0 otherwise, so it's exactly like `UID == 0`. There's no such thing as "boolean" in shell arithmetics,

Comment: I just don't like using a boolean operator on an int.