# single and double equals both behaving differently

Tags: bash

Here's a simple line from a bigger piece of code which is what I am confused about.

```
if [ $some_line == "text" ]
then
```

Then I went on to use the same code for another program that I was working on but the code didn't work UNLESS I changed "==" to "=". I've gone through a few threads here that suggests both of them act the same way so it doesn't matter if you use single or double equals.

```
if [ $some_line = "text" ]
then
```

So the first piece of code works on server1 but doesn't on server2 UNLESS I change it to "single equals". Both the servers have exactly the same environment.

Can anyone explain?
Thanks!

EDIT - I am running the script as "bash myscript.sh" everytime.

Comment: Please [edit[ your question and i) tell us how you are launching the script (`sh script.sh`? `bash script.sh`? Just `script.sh`? Something else?) and also show us the output of `ls -l /bin/sh` on both machines.

Comment: Please explain "does not work". Did it do something unexpected or produce an error, or something else?

Comment: And did you check if you have some special characters in the variable?

Comment: _"So the first piece of code works on server1 but doesn't on server2"_, but _"Both the servers have exactly the same environment."_. I'd say the premise of the question is obviously wrong. If the environment between the servers were the same, both `=` and `==` would behave the same on both of them.

Comment: On the contrary, many answers here such as https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/382012/5132 , https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/16110/5132 , and https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/168288/5132 say that it _does_ matter.

Answer (score 3):

`==` and `=` are equivalent inside `[ ]` tests in `bash`.

`==` doesn't work in `sh`, only `=`

Are you running both scripts with the same shell?

Example:

```
$ cat test1
#!/bin/bash
if [ "a" == "a" ];then echo match;fi
$ ./test1
match
$ cat test2
#!/bin/bash
if [ "a" = "a" ];then echo match;fi
$ ./test2
match
$ cat test3
#!/bin/sh
if [ "a" = "a" ];then echo match;fi
$ ./test3
match
$ cat test4
#!/bin/sh
if [ "a" == "a" ];then echo match;fi
$ ./test4
./test4: 2  [: a: unexpected operator
```

Comment: yeah. The only thing that stands out is that this ubuntu server has not been updated since good amount of time due to development reasons. How can I check if both of them are using the same shell / environment while executing the script?

Comment: run `ps -o comm $$` to know which shell you are in

or `echo $0`

Comment: Since you are using bash, do: `echo "$BASH_VERSION"`